# Extracting the first letter from a string using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

If i have a string say, 1234 Newyork Street, America and i want to extract the first LETTER from the string.

I understand how to use

```
 string.charAt(0);
```

But this extracts for example '1' from the example above. How would i modify the code so if i enter

```
string.charAt(0);
```

I extract the first LETTER which is 'N'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `search` to get the index of the first letter, then use `charAt`:

```
var s = "1234 Newyork Street, America";
s.charAt(s.search(/[a-zA-Z]/));
```

Answer (score 2):

```
string.replace(/[^a-zA-Z]/g, '').charAt(0);
```

This will remove anything that is not a letter, then return the first letter.

Comment: It's just the opposite. It will remove anything which is a letter :P

Comment: @mohamedrias What do you mean?

Comment: string = "1234 Newyork Street, America"
string.replace(/[^a-zA-Z]/, '').charAt(0);
output : "2" , its returning 2

Comment: @mohamedrias Ah, I get you now. Added global flag so it removes all non-letters, rather than just the first.

Answer (score 0):

Both of these will work :

```
string.replace(/^[1-9\s]+/g,"")[0]
```

or

```
replace(/^[1-9\s]+/g,"").charAt(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expression capturing to find the first letter:

```
var s = "1234 Newyork Street, America",
    result = s.match(/([a-zA-Z]).*/),
    firstLetter;

if(result) {
    firstLetter = result[1];
}
```